# SQL Query with all data from lest column and fill blank with previous row value

Tags: mysql, sql

After searching a lot on this forum and the web, i have an issue that i cannot solve without your help.

The requirement look simple but not the code :-(
Basically i need to make a report on cumulative sales by product by week.
I have a table with the calendar (including all the weeks) and a view which gives me all the cumulative values by product and sorted by week. What i need the query to do is to give me all the weeks for each products and then add in a column the cumulative values from the view. if this value does not exist, then it should give me the last know record.

Can you help?

Thanks,

Comment: I disagree with your approach, joins dates and product and apply a cumulative sum rather than trying to downfill.

Comment: Dear P.Salmon, ok i do not mind, so if it is easier or better, then i would have a table with the latest sales plan by product and by week. Can you help me to make the final query?

Comment: Sure, would like to supply representative sample data as text?

Comment: here it is as an extract. Please note that for some products we do not have sales every week so this is the problem: DateWeekNum ProductId Sum of QuantityBatches
202201 7 2
202202 7 2
202202 10 1
202203 7 2
202203 10 1
202204 7 3
202205 7 3
202205 10 2
202206 7 2
202206 10 1
202207 7 2
202208 7 2
202208 10 1
202209 7 2
202209 10 1
202210 7 2
202211 7 3
202211 10 2
202212 7 2

Answer (score 0):

The principal is establish all the weeks that a product could have had sales , sum grouping by week, add the missing weeks and use the sum over window function to get a cumulative sum

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(PROD INT, DT DATE, AMOUNT INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,'2022-01-01', 10),(1,'2022-01-01', 10),(1,'2022-01-20', 10),
(2,'2022-01-10', 10);

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT MIN(YEARWEEK(DT)) MINYW,  MAX(YEARWEEK(DT)) MAXYW FROM T),
CTE1 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT YEARWEEK(DTE) YW ,PROD
  FROM DATES 
 JOIN CTE ON YEARWEEK(DTE) BETWEEN MINYW AND MAXYW
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PROD FROM T) C
 )
SELECT CTE1.YW,CTE1.PROD 
        ,SUMAMT,
        SUM(SUMAMT) OVER(PARTITION BY CTE1.PROD ORDER BY CTE1.YW) CUMSUM
FROM CTE1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT YEARWEEK(DT) YW,PROD ,SUM(AMOUNT) SUMAMT
FROM T 
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(DT),PROD
) S ON S.PROD = CTE1.PROD AND S.YW = CTE1.YW
ORDER BY CTE1.PROD,CTE1.YW
;

 +--------+------+--------+--------+
| YW     | PROD | SUMAMT | CUMSUM |
+--------+------+--------+--------+
| 202152 |    1 |     20 |     20 |
| 202201 |    1 |   NULL |     20 |
| 202202 |    1 |   NULL |     20 |
| 202203 |    1 |     10 |     30 |
| 202152 |    2 |   NULL |   NULL |
| 202201 |    2 |   NULL |   NULL |
| 202202 |    2 |     10 |     10 |
| 202203 |    2 |   NULL |     10 |
+--------+------+--------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.021 sec)
```

Your calendar date may be slightly different to mine but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry if my question is stupied, but i presume that i need to start my querry from WITH CTE AS? Thanks a lot.

Comment: 'i presume that i need to start my querry from WITH CTE AS' - yes and change the table and column names appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i run into a problem, the YEARWEEK function is not recognised in my version

Comment: Really , I think yearweek has always been there what do you get as a result of select version() ?

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server management studio

Comment: Then you probably aren't using mysql and probably are using mssql/sql-server so no surprise that a mysql function does not work there. Does sql-server have a yearweek equivalent - search for sql server date functions. AND you might want to correct the tags on this question and state the version you are on in the question.